# C# Inheritence: Choosing what repository based on type of inherited class

Tags: c#, repository-pattern

I have been making a program that downloads information about movies from the internet. I have a base class `Title`, which represents all titles. `Movie`, `Serie` and `Episode` are inherited from that class.

To save them to the database I have 2 services, `MovieService` and `SerieService`. They in turn call repositories, but that is not important here.

I have a method `Save(Title title)` which I am not very happy with. I check for what type the title is and then call the correct service. I would like to perhaps write like this:

```
ITitleService service = title.GetService();
title.GetSavedBy(service);
```

So I have an abstract method on `Title` that returns an `ITitleSaver`, which will return the correct service for the instance. To do this the services would have to implement `ITitleSaver`

My question is how should I implement `ITitleSaver`? If I make it accept `Title` I will have to cast it to the correct type before calling the correct overload. Which will lead to having to deal with casting once again.

What is the best approach to dealing with this? I would like to have the saving logic in the corresponding class.

Comment: Had you considered having the `Title` implement a `Save()` method, which could be overriden to save in alternate repositories?

Comment: I had it that way from the beginning actually. The problem is that when saving 100 Titles at once, this would lead to creating 100 services.

Comment: `Serie` is not a word in English.

Comment: @Xavier: True. Didn't think about that. I'll change it in my code when I have time :)

Comment: @Oskar Could you allow a single instance to save itself, and derive from (say) `List<Movie>` and have that have a save method that knows how to save collections of `Movie`s?

Comment: @Rowland That might be the best solution. I was hoping for some pattern that would make all this easy :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the purpose of GetService. You only call that method to pass its result to GetSavedBy method? Here is my proposal:

1. Expose an abstract Saver property on the Title class
2. Define a concrete method Save on the Title class whose implementation is:

   this.GetSavedBy(Saver);
3. In each Concrete class either create the required saver or use some dependency injection tool to inject the correct Saver at runtime.

Voila! this solves your problem neatly.

Comment: The purpose of GetService is that I can use the service with other objects and perform other tasks without instantiating new objects. The problem, as stated in the question, is that I'm not sure how to implement ITitleSaver. I need to implement it so that it is the same for Series and Movie, which would lead to dealing with Titles and casting which I do not want to.